# how to use check all in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new in laravel. im tring to create a multiple chekboxs,and click one button then checked all checkboxes im using chekall.blad.php code is here

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    @foreach($students as $student)
        <table border="1" width="220" >
            <tr>
                <td width="130">
                    <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="student[]" id="{{$student}}" >    
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$student->studname}}
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

i dont know using jquery code.can you explain jquery code for checkall

and i want to checked values are save into database table.

Comment: I think it is best to read the documentation for jquery to understand the principles of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all of them by running this jquery code:

```
$.each( $("input[id^='myInputIDStatusStartWith']"), function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Where myInputIDStatusStartWith is that part of your input ids which is similar.

You can change your button into:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="checkAllCheckboxes()">
```

And you can define this function "checkAllCheckboxes" in a JavaScript script like:

```
function checkAllCheckboxes(){
    $.each( $("input[id^='myInputIDStatusStartWith']"), function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
}
```

Don't forget to include the jquery library in your page.

Comment: srry i can't understand ..if you dont mine can you explain that code?

Comment: It's best to completely separate js and use an eventlistener for the submit button

Comment: $.each will iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element. In this case your jQuery object is composed by all inputs with their id starting like 'myInputIDStatusStartWith'.

Comment: srry its not working...my checkall.blade.php code is here .....<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
function checkAllCheckboxes(){
    $.each( $("input[id^='myInputIDStatusStartWith']"), function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });}
</script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="checkAllCheckboxes()">
   @foreach($students as $student)

 <tr>
  <td width="130">
    <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="student[]" id="{{$student}}" ></td>
    <td>{{$student->studname}}</td> 
</tr>
@endforeach

Comment: :) You have to change 'myInputIDStatusStartWith' with the first part of your  inputs id. I mean replace 'myInputIDStatusStartWith' with the common part of what {{$student}} is returning.

Comment: thank you sir its working.... but i want one more help ...im  click checkall button then check all checkboxes..(im display all checkboxes and student names) then im add a new submit button in below.when im click that button all checked values(student names) are save into database. table..how its possible??? can you explain controller code???

Comment: What do you want to know ? You will read the values in laravel like: $page = Input::get('page', ''); . After that you will insert them in your DB like: DB::table('users')->insert(
    array('email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0)
);

Comment: this code ok..but im selected multiple values (more than one "eg: 5 students") how can i insert these all values into the database in one row??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this jQuery code :

```js
$("table").each(function(e){
    $(this).find("input").attr('checked', true);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="220" >
 <tr>
   <td width="130">
    <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" ></td>
   <td>a</td> 
</tr></table>
<table border="1" width="220" >
 <tr>
   <td width="130">
    <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="b" id="b" ></td>
   <td>a</td> 
</tr></table>
<table border="1" width="220" >
 <tr>
   <td width="130">
    <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="b" id="b" ></td>
   <td>a</td> 
</tr></table>
```